# How do you Record Macros on Sharepoint Designer?

Tags: microsoft-office, sharepoint

VBA is included with Sharepoint Designer. With Word, I normally record a macro and then add to it with VBA. However, I cannot find a macro record function with Sharepoint Designer. Is it possible to record a macro with Sharepoint? If not, is there any documentation of the available editing commands you can use in a macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no macro record function in SharePoint Designer.

For the documentation, I suggest the reference page of this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb149156%28v=office.12%29.aspx).